# Do we like things better or more?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference

I've always thought about why some people say, for example:

> I like this web browser **better** than the other one.

When they probably should say:

> I like this web browser **more** than the other one.

I don't see how people can like one thing better than another, but maybe **better** really means **more**? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The two are interchangeable, at least as regards liking things.

> **better**  *adv*
>   2. a. To a greater extent or degree: *better suited to the job; likes it better without sauce.*
>
> **more** *adv*
>   1. a. To or in a greater extent or degree: *loved him even more*.

Short answer: You can like things more and you can like them better. The choice is yours.

[Definitions from TheFreeDictionaryOnline](https://www.thefreedictionary.com)